# Mysql: Generate procedure using a function

Tags: mysql

First of all just wanted to state that i'm a new student so my level of knowledge might not be as high as some others in here.

I have to create a database as part of the project my DB is about NBA (it hasnt to be big , or complicated , but it must work smoothly and be "efficient") and right now i'm struggling with the function/procedure part of it. so let me explain it what is all about.

I can create a select that shows

IdGame - 1

Date - 2018-01-01

HomeResult - 110

AwayResult - 111

OT - 0

IdHomeTeam - 1

IdAwayTeam - 2

also did a function with a lot of effort from a newcomer like me XD that once introduced the IdGame is able to return the ID of the team with higher Result (A.K.A. Winner)

```
MariaDB [NBATEST]> Select Winner(1);
+--------------+
| Winner(1)    |
+--------------+
|            2 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Next step is using the function showed above i need to create a procedure that using this function would update the Wins , Loses of the two teams (I assume with and If Winner (Win +1) , Else Loser (loses +1)) and generate a trigger that uses the procedure everytime user adds a game record to the table.

**Question 1** Is this idea right? Function -> Procedure(That uses the function) -> Trigger(that uses the procedure)?

Comment: Is this idea right? in what way I wonder. If the question is will this work then yes From where I sit the function and procedure seem unnecessary.

Comment: I'm somehow stuck thinking the right process that leads me to the point that where having a Game entry (with mainly two TeamId and two scores) compare both scores and assigns TeamId Winner and TeamId2 Loser  (I have two functions that does that) then a trigger that sums +1 to victory/lose on each Team column